# Multiple for loops in java not working properly

Tags: java, loops

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Java and I've been working on a simple program which creates a grid with multiple slots. Each slot has an X and a Y value and is stored in an ArrayList called "s".

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        s.add(new Slot(j, i));
    }
}
```

Height and width are user inputed values.

It's a simple loop within a loop and essentially it should work but instead of creating multiple slots with the values 0, 0,  1,0  2, 0  3, 0 and so forth until it should increase the Y axis by one it never increases the Y-value. Instead after doing the first loop it will go back to 0, 0 instead of 0, 1.

Also here's the how it's supposed to print the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++) {
        System.out.print(s.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Example:

> 0,0
>
> 1,0
>
> 2,0
>
> 3,0
>
> ...
>
> 9,0
>
> 0,0 (instead of 0,1)

My question is why on earth doesn't my first loop ever increase the value of i? Sorry if I sound like an idiot, I'm a total noob.

Comment: Could you add your `Slot` class? I see nothing wrong right here, and I am afraid your `Slot` constructor fails to copy the `i` value properly into an instance field...

Comment: The loops work properly. Your code does not. Post more code, especially declarations of `s` and `Slot`. Moreover: if you continue naming your variables `s` you will get lost very, very soon.

Comment: Is that the complete loop code, you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are storing height * width elements in a one dimensional array - ArrayList but retreiving only width number of elements.

Instead of arraylist of Slot for s, use two dimensional array.

```
Slot[][] s = new Slot[width][height];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        s[j][i](new Slot(j, i));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++) {
            System.out.print(s[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard about two dimensional arrays (as I said I'm new. I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your printing function.

I don't know what `s` is but:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++) {
            System.out.print(s.get(j));
        }
        System.out.println("");
 }
```

Get objects based on `j` value only. You need to get objects based on `i` and `j` in order to get all values.
Or you can just iterate over all objects in `s` (if `s` is a `Collection`):

```
for (Slot sl : s) {
    System.out.println(sl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the print function. Just iterate over `s` and print each slot:

```
for (Slot slot : s) {
    System.out.println(slot);
}
```

As it is implemented now, you print items in `s` from indexes `0` -> `width` over and over again, `height` times.

Also, learn about the **for-each** loop, available from Java 5 instead of using `get(index)`:

[Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `j` value only ranges between 0 and `width - 1` so `s.get(j)` is only going to access the first `width` items in `s`.  Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++) {
        System.out.print(s.get(i * width + j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Or you could just iterate over the contents of `s` and not use nested `for` loops for the retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the nested loop when printing, Just iterate over the ArrayList:

```
for(Slot slot : s )
{
    System.out.println(slot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only print j from the same place every time